# Run a Loop of maximum digits of number

Tags: java, arrays, loops, coding-style

Eg. We have a number 355 then its digit counts are 3.
We have to write a program in Java which runs a loop from 100 to 999.
If digits are 4 then run a loop from 1000 to 9999.
If 5 then 10000 to 99999.

Comment: Please make an [attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at writing some [code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). If you get stuck please do some [research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) and provide details of what you found and why it does not solve your problem. See the [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `digits` is 4, then your loop boundaries are 10<sup>3</sup> (1000) and 10<sup>4</sup> - 1 (9999).

In Java, you can use [`Math.pow(double a, double b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-) to calculate a<sup>b</sup>, making it easy to calculate the upper and lower boundaries:

```
int min = (int) Math.pow(10, digits - 1);
int max = min * 10 - 1;
```

Then you just write a `for` loop using those values.

Answer (score -1):

I really don't know if understand your question...
This loop will run as many times as there are digits in num

```
int num = 1000;
String str = "" + num;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: Joe but I want to run if no. Of digits are 3 then the lower bound is 100 and upper bound is 999 the loop should be run between these bounds.